# Prove that $\sigma^*$ is the least group congruence on $S$

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, congruences, semigroups, congruence-relations

Let $S$ be an inverse semigroup and consider the relation $\sigma$ on $S$ given by $$a \sigma b \iff ab^{-1} \in E(S)$$
Consider the congruence generated by $\sigma$, say $\sigma^*$.

> Prove that $\sigma^*$ is the least group congruence on $S$.

That $\sigma^*$ is a congruence it is.

I don't know how to prove that $S/\sigma^*$ is a group and that if $\rho$ is a group congruence, $\sigma^* \subseteq \rho$.

Can someone give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: What is $E(S)$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber - According to Wikipedia,  "E(S) <denotes> the semilattice of idempotents of an inverse semigroup S". So $a\sigma b \iff (ab^{-1})(ab^{-1}) = ab^{-1}$

Comment: If $S$ is a semigroup, denote by $E(S)$ the set of idempotents of $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Towards showing that $S/\sigma^*$ is a group: can you show that (the equivalence class corresponding to) $aa^{-1}$ is an identity in $S/\sigma^*$? More precisely: that $baa^{-1}\sigma b$ for any $b$?

Towards showing that $\sigma^*$ is the least group congruence: suppose $S/\rho$ is a group. Then show that if $a\sigma b$, the equivalence class corresponding to $ab^{-1}$ is an idempotent in $S/\rho$. But what are the idempotents in a group?

Comment: @Leafar Well at that point, what other group axioms do you need to check? And, do you see why they're true?

Comment: The group part I think I got it, because we have the properties $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$ and $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$

Comment: But in the second part,I suppose that $S/\rho$ is a group and I take $(a,b) \in \sigma$. We want to prove that $(a,b) \in \rho$ (note that this imply $\sigma^* \subseteq \rho$ because $\sigma^*$ is the least congruence that contains $\sigma$). So we have $a \sigma b$, then $ab^{-1} \in E(S)$. With this fact we obtain that $[ab^{-1}]_{\rho} \in E(S/\rho)$. But $S/\rho$ is a group, then $[ab^{-1}]_{\rho}$ is the identity of $S/\rho$. What can I say next @Noah Schweber ?