# Definition of a least group congruence

Tags: congruences, semigroups

I'm just trying to find the definition of a least group congruence for a semigroup S. I'm reading papers on E-inversive semigroups and they often bring up least group congruences but none have a definition.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you look at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623128/prove-that-sigma-is-the-least-group-congruence-on-s)?

Comment: I hadn't. That's very helpful, thanks!